# sql transaction error

Tags: mysql, sql, sqltransaction

I am very new to SQL. I am at a loss as to what my problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE hsitems SET price = price *2 WHERE partID = AX12;
COMMIT;
```

## 1054 - Unknown column 'AX12' in 'where clause'

Comment: id AX12 is a string, you need to write `"AX12"`

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me that there's no column named `AX12`. If it's a value to compare against, it should be enclosed in single quotes as in `'AX12'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE hsitems SET price = price *2 WHERE partID = "AX12";
```

That is assuming the partID is a varchar or char column.

Comment: Question should be closed because it's a typo.